# Изучаю сортировку подсчётом на Паскале

Tags: pascalabc.net

Только начала разбираться в программировании. Дан псевдокод

```
 var
     arr: array[-1000..1000] of longint; //arr[i] - количество чисел i в массиве
     i, j, n, x: longint;
    begin
     readln(n);
     for i := -1000 to 1000 do
      arr[i] := 0;
     for i := 1 to n do 
    begin
     read(x);
    inc(arr[x]);
     end;
    for i := -1000 to 1000 do
    for j := 1 to arr[i] do
    write(i, ' ');
    end.
```

По сути он работает как сортировщик подсчётом, но я категорически не пойму, каким способом он его производит. Я понимаю, как вводятся и выводятся числа, но как они сортируются - непонятно. Может кто-нибудь популярно объяснить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну сортировки как таковой тут и не производится.

```
for i := 1 to n do 
begin
    read(x);
    inc(arr[x]);
end;
```

Здесь, элемент массива, соответствующий введенному числу инкрементируем. (Если число было введено H раз, то это элемент будет равен H).

```
for i := -1000 to 1000 do 
    for j := 1 to arr[i] do 
        write(i, ' ');
```

А здесь — проходимся по каждому элементу массива. И проходим циклом от 1 до значения элемента массива, а в этот элемент ранее было записано количество таких чисел. Если значение было 0(таких чисел не было введено, то мы ничего и не выведем), если значение было, например 2 — то выведем два раза подряд это число.

Вроде постарался описать понятным языком...

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  // сортировка подсчётом
  var n := ReadInteger('Укажите количество чисел:');
  var a := ReadArrInteger('Вводите:', n);
  var k := a.Max;
  var c := |0| * (k + 1);
  for var i := 0 to a.High do
    c[a[i]] += 1;
  var b := 0;
  for var j := 0 to k do
    for var i := 0 to c[j] - 1 do
    begin
      a[b] := j;
      b += 1
    end;
  a.Println
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]